# Get data from function to function in controller codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I am a newbie on codeigniter and am stuck with a problem. Can you help me understand how to get data from a function in 1 controller, i tried with simple code like this

```
public function cow() {
        $first=$this->input->post('name');
}

public function bird() {
    // how to display variable $first = " hello world" in here
}
```

i hope you can help me guys, :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this both is the same controller, you can use `$this` to access the function

```
public function cow() {
    $first= 'some text';
    return $first; # Add this
}

public function bird() {
   echo  $this->cow();
}
```

> Note: If you're getting input from form, then you can't access it through the bird function

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: can you help me again ?

Comment: whats up? explain

Comment: i will create post again, please wait